# Send a virtual POST request to a Sails server using Socket.io swift client

Tags: ios, socket.io, swift3, sails.js

I'm developing a **iOS** app and im using the SocketIO Swift SDK for connecting to a server with Sails(v0.12.11). I want to know how i can emit to a url (e.g I want to broadcast to all users) i tried:

```
   socket.emit("post", ["data": ["message": "Hello World"], "url": "/user/broadcast"])
```

Unfortunately, it won't trigger Sails to trigger the controller/action. When I make the same request via HTTP I see a new message in the log file.

Does someone know how to make the virtual get request?

Comment: are you able to call virtual GET request?

Answer (score 1):

I remember our iOS developers struggled with this also...

After a while, we realised sails socket need to be connected with additional query params...

This is c/p from one of the projects where we connect to sails socket...

```
 let socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: socketURL)!, options: Set(arrayLiteral: SocketIOClientOption.Log(true), .ConnectParams(["__sails_io_sdk_version": "0.11.0"])))
```

As you can see we are passing __sails_io_sdk_version": "0.11.0" to connection...

Try sending this and check if it works...

Comment: Thanks for your information, but I already had sorted this out. How did you team send data to the server, by http or ws?